# How is the flow for Angular to backend services?

Tags: angular

I would like to clarify. How is the flow for angular applications?

Does it moves from `browser` -> `backend`

or

`browser`-> `angular app` -> `backend`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Browser calls the angular app. Angular is JavaScript in the frontend (browser). Angular can send http requests to a backend (php, java, node, .net or so).

So the BROWSER calls the ANGULAR APP which can send requests to BACKEND.